# I'm getting a StaleDataException

Tags: android, listview, filter

I have a class where I want to filter a list using an edit text, I am however getting a StaleDataException whenever the edit text is being brought back to blank, so the user types in data and deletes it until the editText is blank and this is where the exception is fired. So this is my code.

```
public class CBFilter extends ListActivity {

EditText Filter;
ListView RecipeNames;
Cursor cursor;
CBListAdapter adapter;
CBDataBaseHelper data;
SQLiteDatabase data2;
TextView RecipeText, RowId;
String[] from = { CBDataBaseHelper.KEY_NAME};
int[] to = { R.id.rowText};
ImageView image;
byte[] dataImage;
BufferedInputStream buf;
public static final String TAG = "Error";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

//FileInputStream in;//= openFileInput("//STEFAN-PC/Users/stefan/Desktop/Uni Work/Image.jpg");
RecipeNames = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
RecipeNames.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
RecipeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeText);
Filter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_box);

//adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (this, 0, cursor, null, null);
//image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.RecipeImage);
data = new CBDataBaseHelper(this);
data.open();
cursor = data.query();
startManagingCursor(cursor);
adapter = new CBListAdapter(this, 0, cursor, from, to);
RecipeNames.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        try{
    CBListAdapter filteradapter = (CBListAdapter)RecipeNames.getAdapter();


    filteradapter.setFilterQueryProvider(filterQueryProvider);

    //RecipeNames.setAdapter(filteradapter);

    filteradapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    filteradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }catch(Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG, "sumthing wrong", e);
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {


    }




});
}



public void CreateNew(View view){

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, CBCreate.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(parent, v, position, id);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CBCreate.class);
    long rowId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CBDataBaseHelper.KEY_ROWID));
    String s = String.valueOf(rowId);
    intent1.putExtra("SELECTED", s);
    startActivity(intent1);
}


 public FilterQueryProvider filterQueryProvider = new FilterQueryProvider() {

        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence _constraint) {
           // CBDataBaseHelper dh2;
            Cursor c = data.findRecipe((String) _constraint);
            startManagingCursor(c);
            Cursor cur = data.query();
            startManagingCursor(cur);
            cur.requery();

            if (_constraint == null | _constraint.length() == 0) {
                return cur;
            }

            return c;
        }

    };





}
```

and this is what is showing in my logCat.

```
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333): android.database.StaleDataException:  Access closed cursor
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:217)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at pkg.CookBook.CBListAdapter.getView(CBListAdapter.java:41)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.view.View.layout (View.java:7034)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1049)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-15 01:09:00.557: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12333):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: why ur using cur.requery(); after startManagingCursor(cur); in the following code Cursor cur = data.query(); startManagingCursor(cur); cur.requery();

Comment: i have removed requery and i am still getting this error.

Comment: When we use startManagingCursor() the cursor instance is closed

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to retrieve information from a Cursor that has already been closed. You must verify whether the cursor is closed/not by using the  [isClosed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#isClosed%28%29) method.

```
    Cursor cur = data.query();
      if (TextUtils.isEmpty((_constraint )){

      if (cur != null && cur .moveToFirst()) {
         return cur ;

    }
 }

cur.close();
```

Comment: so if i wrapped that code in a if, say if (!isClosed) then do that code, but why is the cursor closed? i'm not closing it anywhere

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startManagingCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29

Comment: startManagingCursor method is depricated

Comment: Stefan Reaney.. could u pls put try catch and find at which point the exception is thrown

Comment: i think the exception is thrown is in this line if (_constraint == null | _constraint.length() == 0) { return cur; } : check inside that condition whether the cursor is closed or not

Comment: hmmm i have wrapped this line into an if isClosed().. the exception is still being thrown suggesting that the error is somewhere else in this method